# Access the certain key of json response [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Here is my angular code

```
$scope.StartCPU = function () {

//Initialize the Timer to run every 1000 milliseconds i.e. one second.
            $scope.GetCPUData = $interval(function(){
              $http.get('http://localhost:3034/api/test/metrics').
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.Details = data;
             });}, 1000);  
        };
```

Html code as follows

```
<div ng-controller="HttpGetController">
    <button ng-click="StartCPU()">Get All Data</button> 
    <h1>CPU data</h1>
    <pre>{{Details | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

I am getting the response as below

```
{
  "data": [
  {
    "_id": "57ee5641931b429431085fc4",
    "system": 0.06249,
    "process": 0.0091652,
    "timestamp": "2016-09-30T12:10:40.780Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "createdAt": "2016-09-30T12:10:41.927Z"
  }
]
}
```

Now I want to access the value of the keys "system" and "process". How can I do it?

Comment: `<h1 ng-bind="Details.data[0].system"></h1>` will result in `<h1>0.06249>/h1>`

Answer (score 2):

```
data.data[0].system
```

and `data.data[0].process`

Explanation: Here your `data` is an `Object` with property `data`.

```
//complete thing is your response data
{
  "data": [ // data.data <--array
  { // data.data[0] <--first object of the array
    "_id": "57ee5641931b429431085fc4",
    "system": 0.06249,// data.data[0].system <--its property
    "process": 0.0091652,
    "timestamp": "2016-09-30T12:10:40.780Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "createdAt": "2016-09-30T12:10:41.927Z"
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `data` object that you get from the call, you have the property`data` which is an array

You should then call the first element of the array

```
data.data[0]
```

Which will return you

```
  {
    "_id": "57ee5641931b429431085fc4",
    "system": 0.06249,
    "process": 0.0091652,
    "timestamp": "2016-09-30T12:10:40.780Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "createdAt": "2016-09-30T12:10:41.927Z"
  }
```

Then you call the elements that you need

```
data.data[0].system

data.data[0].process
```

Answer (score 0):

It means it returns an array, may you can use something like this:

```html
<table class="table datatable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
      <th>system</th>
      <th>process</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody ng-repeat="detail in Details">
  <tr>
      <td>{{detail.system}}</td>
      <td>{{detail.process}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```